# jQuery Mobile not working through SSLVPN

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, vpn

**Update** Error in Firebug console error below. Thanks to `Jasper` since I didn't think of it. `my.url.com` is my change, but it is the correct address to reference something through the SSLVPN.

> ```
> Security error
> https://my.url.com/mobile/1.1.0/,DanaInfo=code.jquery.com,CT=js+jquery.mobile-1.1.0.js
> Line 3903
> ```

The code at this spot is within `jquery.mobile-1.1.0.js`

```
init: function() {
  $win.bind( "hashchange", self.onHashChange );
  // Handle popstate events the occur through history changes
  $win.bind( "popstate", self.onPopState );
  // if there's no hash, we need to replacestate for returning to home
  if ( DanaGetHash(location) === "" ) {
    history.replaceState( self.state(), document.title, DanaGetHref(location) );
  }
}
```

Looks like `DanaGetHash` and `DanaGetHref` are added by the SSLVPN.

**Original** I have created a mobile page using jQuery Mobile and I've run in to an issue that works perfectly fine when accessed from a computer non-SSLVPN within our network, but when it is accessed through our SSLVPN, the page is broken badly.

Within IE8 and IE9, the front page displays but none of the subsequent pages that are links via a `listview` will even try to display. Clicking on a link displays the *waiting spinner* but never displays the page.

Within Chrome and Firefox, the front page is blank.

I've tried using a CDN for jQuery as well as a local copy within a relative directory.

- Our SSLVPN is Juniper
- jQuery 1.7.2 **non-minimized**
- jQuery Mobile 1.1.0 **non-minimized**

Feel free to ask for any details you may need and any help is appreciated.

Comment: What does your error console say for JS errors?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I didn't think to look. I posted the error message in the solution so it is seen easier.

Comment: I am facing a similar problem with SSLVPN - though not Juniper. What exactly is the Dana stuff - is it something specific to Juniper?

Comment: It's specific to Juniper. Unfortunately the only real suggestions I can think of are in the answer I accepted below. Basically host the scripts in a relative directory, non-minimized and prevent any SSLVPN rewrite if you can. The issue was with the rewrites and also Javascript injection done by the SSLVPN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case it is of interest to anyone else, how this was resolved was two things with Juniper SSLVPN.

1. We had to use a pass-through method as opposed to a re-write. JQuery and re-write are not friends. So in order to get jQuery working, we had to proxy the access after login. I am told by Juniper that this is very common for Sharepoint in general as a lot of re-writes tend to fail on a Sharepoint site.
2. Hosted and referenced the jQuery scripts locally. This is important because (from Juniper’s explanation) we can’t pass through proxy to an external site and we can’t re-write a external site through a pass-through proxy.

Hope this is of interest to someone.

Comment: Thanks for this post! It saved my what would most likely have been hours of debugging and troubleshooting for my jQuery Mobile app that needs to be available through SSLVPN.

Answer (score 2):

To Anyone that might bump into this problem,
I was able to solve the issue by configuring a selective rewriting rule that would avoid rewriting the specific js file. no bad-for-security pass-through proxy required.

**Resource**: `http://my.site/lib/jquery.mobile-1.0rc1.js`

**Policy applies to SELECTED roles:** my_mobileapp_role

**Action**: Don't rewrite content: Do not redirect to target web server

The page would then load properly.
Hope i have helped someone.